# set dynamic uploader for carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I am looking to dynamically set the uploader based on objects attribute.

```
#Something like this in the user.rb
mount_uploader :avatar, Avatar2Uploader,:if => Proc.new{|p| p.migrated == false }
mount_uploader :avatar, Avatar1Uploader,:if => Proc.new{|p| p.migrated == true }
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What is the use-case for having two different carrierwave uploaders for the same Model?

Comment: what have the  `migrated` method? The object or the class? Also, `x == true` can always be substituted by simply `x`.

Comment: @KirtiThorat, we have been using fog as our storage and recently decided to use mongo. The plan is to migrate users in batch, until the  migration is completely done fog and mongo storage has to co-exist and the storage has be selected based on the users migration flag set in the table. Dynamically Switching the storage is not possible at the object level, so I decided to have separate uploader class that can be toggled by the objects migrated flag.